# How to update Multiple row through post request in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How to update multiple rows through post request in laravel when i submit the code it shows an error like `Array to string conversion`.

**How can i solve this issue any body help thanks in advance?**

[image]

post form here

[image]

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="{{ route('multiple') }}">
                                {{csrf_field()}}
                                @foreach($classes as $class)
                                <div class="">
                                   <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="id[]" value="{{$class->id}}">

                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" value="{{$class->name}}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <input id="class" type="text" class="form-control" name="class[]" value="{{$class->class}}">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                 @endforeach
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                           submit
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
this is method

    public function post_loop(Request $request)
        {
            foreach ($request as $data ) 
            {
                $values = array(
                    'name' => $request->name,
                    'class' => $request->class,
                );
                DB::table('multiple_data')->whereIn('id',$request->id)->update($values);

            }
    }
```

Comment: Please give me a screenshot of your error?

Comment: Why we need foreach loop here?

Comment: multiple rows which is passing from post form

Comment: Why there is foreach?

Comment: we need multiple rows to update

Comment: I believe $request is an object that contains multiple values and you are treating it as a single object. This creating a problem for you.

Comment: how can i solve this

Comment: First you should get the data from request like `$id = $request->input('id')`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is completely wrong. The `request` is a object and has many data about the request. But you are using it as an array to get your input.

Try this code.

```
$ids = $request->input('id');
$names = $request->input('name');
$classes = $request->input('class');

foreach($ids as $k => $id){

  $values = array(
                    'name' => $names[$k],
                    'class' => $classes[$k],
                );

  DB::table('yourTable')->where('id','=',$id)->update($values);

}
```